# How to use a wildcard for filenames in batch command For?

Tags: batch-file

This batch line works with full filenames:

```
for /f "skip=3 delims=*" %%g in (cc_data_3-3-2016_15-37-19.xml  cc_data_3-28-2016_0-25-36.xml) do (echo %%g >>tempfile.txt)
```

This one doesn't when filenames are replaced by a wildcard:

```
for /f "skip=3 delims=*" %%g in (*.xml) do (echo %%g >>tempfile.txt)
```

What's wrong and what should I do to make it work? I need the *.xml files. They are in the same folder as the batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for /f` takes a filename only.  If you want to use a wildcard, you'll need to expand the wildcards yourself.  You can use `for` to do that, just not in one call:

```
for %%f in (*.xml) do (
    for /f "skip=3 delims=*" %%g in (%%f) do (echo %%g >>tempfile.txt)
)
```

Comment: @Anon_C What a wonderful solution! It works like a charm. Thank you so much. Where can I find some documentation about this arcane feature?

Comment: Instead of `echo %%g >>tempfile.txt` I would write `>> tempfile.txt echo %%g` in order to avoid a trailing space to be echoed too...

Comment: @AnonCoward Then why `for %%f in (*.xml)` without parameter `/f` can `do`something?

Comment: Because that does take a wildcard and returns filenames from the filesystem.